# C LinkedList pointer not working with dynamically allocated array

Tags: c

I am trying to assign a LinkedList variable using a pointer but get an error. Here is my code.

```
typedef struct {
  struct Vertex *next;
} Vertex;
typedef struct {
  Vertex *vertices;
} Environment;
// here I dynamically allocate an array of vertexs, 28 to be specific
env->vertices = (Vertex *)malloc(7*sizeof(Vertex));
//this code is just to understand what I am trying to achieve
env->vertices[0].next = env->vertices[1];
```

I get an error saying that I am trying to assign a Vertex to a Vertex*. Any ideas?

Comment: `env->vertices[0].next` is a `Vertex *` and `env->vertices[1]` is a `Vertex`. What part of that don't you understand?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I am not quite sure how to make them pointers I guess, how would I do that? I tried a couple things with the malloc but no luck. I have tried also passing the address but that doesn't seem to work. Gives an incompatible pointer type

Comment: "I have tried also passing the address but that doesn't seem to work." What code exactly did you try for that?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica just adding a & infront of the env->vertices[1]

Answer (score 1):

Passing the address is exactly what you need to do. You just forgot an instance of the word `Vertex`. Your first declaration should be this:

```
typedef struct Vertex {
  struct Vertex *next;
} Vertex;
```

Once you fix that, you can do `env->vertices[0].next = &env->vertices[1];` without an incompatible pointer type warning.

Comment: That makes sense, did not know I needed to do that! Should I be doing that for all forward referencing structs?

Comment: @Lamar Yes, if they're self-referential. Otherwise, they'll refer to an incomplete type with a coincidentally similar name, and not to themselves.

Answer (score 0):

```
env->vertices[0].next = (env->vertices+1);
//Or
env->vertices[0].next = &(env->vertices[1]);
```

Comment: Both of these give an incompatible pointer type. Maybe I should be declaring it as pointers in the malloc? What do you think

Comment: struct Vertex {
      struct Vertex *next;
    } MyVertex;
    typedef struct {
        struct Vertex *vertices;
    } Environment;

    Environment *env = malloc(sizeof(Environment));
    // here I dynamically allocate an array of vertexs, 28 to be specific
    env->vertices = malloc(7*sizeof(MyVertex));